# if you have 2.5 * 10^21 atoms of magnesium how many moles do you have?

Tags: stoichiometry, mole

If you have $\pu{2.5 * 10^21}$ atoms of magnesium, how many moles do you have?

Comment: What have you trief so far? How is a mole defined? This is a homework question, it needs to show some effort from you what you have tried to solve the problem.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

divide however many atoms you have (2.5*10^21) by 6.022*10^23 - Avogadro's Constant

Comment: why was this voted down?!

Comment: Read the "[Why don't you provide a complete answer to homework questions?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange/142#142)" section of the homework policy

Comment: I don't really care about people answering homework questions. However if you do want to answer them, you need to do it properly (as with *any* other question on this website). Your answer doesn't explain anything, it just states the solution. It would be more helpful if you explained what a mole is, the significance of Avogadro's number, ...